# Inputting a Equation in Textfield and Processing it? [actionscript 3.0]

Tags: flash, numbers

I would like to know if theirs a way where you can type in a text field something like "5*5".

And then on enter, the document would take the database and be able to return 25.

I am quite confused due to the fact that content that you input into a textfield must be a `String` and when you use the `Number()` converter the system gets confused.

Comment: You can parse the string and look for operators like + - * and / and then perform the correct operation on the numbers on either side of those operators.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to break your string apart at operators (using regex) and then keep those operators.

I don't have the patience to do this myself but you'll need to prioritise certain operations as well (multiplication before addition, etc).

I've done some code to get you started - note that it only works with really simple algorithms in its current form:

```
// Finds +, - and *.
var operators:RegExp = /\+|\-|\*/g;
var numbers:RegExp = /\d+/g;


/**
 * Attempts to work with a mathematical formula provided as string.
 * @param str Subject string.
 */
function work(str:String):Number
{
    var ops:Array = str.match(operators);   // List of operators in order.
    var nums:Array = str.match(numbers);    // List of numbers in order.

    var command:Array = [];
    var cmbLen:int = Math.max(ops.length, nums.length);

    for(var i:int = 0; i < cmbLen; i++)
    {
        if(nums[i]) command.push(nums[i]);
        if(ops[i]) command.push(ops[i]);
    }


    // Begin performing the command.
    var val:Number = 0;
    var queuedOperator:String = "";

    for(i = 0; i < command.length; i++)
    {
        // Apply initial value;
        if(i == 0)
            val = Number(command[i]);

        // Work.
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            var num:Number = Number(command[i]);

            // Operate if required.
            if(queuedOperator.length > 0)
            {
                switch(queuedOperator)
                {
                    case "+": val += num; break;
                    case "-": val -= num; break;
                    case "*": val *= num; break;
                }
            }

            queuedOperator = command[i + 1] as String || "";
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

And some testing:

```
trace(work("7 + 10")); // 17
trace(work("5 * 5")); // 25
trace(work("12 - 4")); // 8

trace(work("10 + 5 + 1")); // 16
```

Feel free to build on this to include more operators (just add them into `operators`) and sort the `command` in order of priority. Adding `()` parenthesis will start to get interesting but with time I'm sure it's possible to get working right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using **RegExp**. This can calculate whole and decimal numbers using the following signs: `^`,`%`,`/`,`*`,`+`,`-`. You can also use parantheses e.g. `2^(10/(2+3-2))`.

You will need to select the *disable keyboard shortcuts* option from the control menu when in *test movie* mode to see the result.

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,tfKeyDown);
tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('_sans',24);
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
tf.border = true;
tf.x = (stage.stageWidth - 300) * .5;
tf.y = 100;
tf.width = 200;
addChild(tf);
stage.focus = tf;


function tfKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
        e.preventDefault();
        trace('Input:',tf.text);
        trace('Result:',calculate(tf.text,7));
        trace('-----------------------');
    }
}

function calculate(str:String,maxDecimalCount:int=int.MAX_VALUE):Number {

    var num:String = '-?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+';
    var numRX:RegExp = new RegExp(num,'g');
    var rx:RegExp, i:int;

    // normalize minuses and eliminate spaces
    str = str.replace(/--/g,'+').replace(/\s/g,'');

    // calculate parenthesized equations
    while (/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/.test(str)) {
        str = str.replace(/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/g,function() {
            return calculate(String(arguments[1]),int.MAX_VALUE).toString();
        });
    }

    // exponential --> x^y
    rx = new RegExp(num+'(\\^'+num+')+','g');
    str = str.replace(rx,function() {
        var nums = String(arguments[0]).match(numRX);
        var res:Number = Math.pow(Number(nums[0]),Number(nums[1]));
        for (i = 2; i < nums.length; i++) res = Math.pow(res,Number(nums[i]));
        //trace('^ ['+nums+'] =',res);
        return res;
    });
    // modulus --> x%y
    rx = new RegExp(num+'(%'+num+')+','g');
    str = str.replace(rx,function() {
        var nums = String(arguments[0]).match(numRX);
        var res:Number = Number(nums[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) res %= Number(nums[i]);
        //trace('% ['+nums+'] =',res);
        return res;
    });
    // divide --> x/y
    rx = new RegExp(num+'(/'+num+')+','g');
    str = str.replace(rx,function() {
        var nums = String(arguments[0]).match(numRX);
        var res:Number = Number(nums[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) res /= Number(nums[i]);
        //trace('/ ['+nums+'] =',res);
        return res;
    });
    // multiply --> x*y
    rx = new RegExp(num+'(\\*'+num+')+','g');
    str = str.replace(rx,function() {
        var nums = String(arguments[0]).match(numRX);
        var res:Number = Number(nums[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) res *= Number(nums[i]);
        //trace('* ['+nums+'] =',res);
        return res;
    });
    // add or subtract --> x+y or x-y
    rx = new RegExp(num+'([\\+\\-]'+num+')+','g');
    str = str.replace(rx,function() {
        var nums = String(arguments[0]).match(numRX);
        var res:Number = Number(nums[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) res += Number(nums[i]);
        //trace('+- ['+nums+'] =',res);
        return res;
    });

    var res:Number = Number(str);
    // if the result is not a number...
    if (isNaN(res)) {
        throw new Error('Please input a valid equation using numbers and the following signs: ()^%/*+-');
    }
    // if the remainder needs to be shortened...
    if (maxDecimalCount < int.MAX_VALUE &&
        int(res) != res && String(res).split('.')[1].length > maxDecimalCount) {
        res = Math.round(res * Math.pow(10,maxDecimalCount)) / Math.pow(10,maxDecimalCount);
    }
    return res; 

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where modulus and exponential should be in the order, though. That might need a change.