# ActionScript 3: Turning a String into and Operator?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, operators, calculator

I'm trying to create a simple calculator program in ActionScript for a school project, and I'm struggling to find a concise way to take an equation from an array such as this: "4","+","2"; and manipulate it so that the answer to the equation can be deduced. The problem is taking the String "+" from the equation array and turning it into a usable operator. At the moment, when an operator button is pressed on the calculator GUI it adds the operator to the equation array as a String (i.e. pressing the '÷' button will add "/" to the equation array).

I looked for an answer to this on Google and found [something about a JavaScript function](https://forums.adobe.com/message/2855191) that I used in the code below (in lines 1 and 4), but all I end up with in the Output feed is "null", or "0" depending on whether I changed the variable 'answer' to a String, or a Number.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var equationArray:Array = new Array("4","+","2");
var answer:Number = ExternalInterface.call("eval",equationArray[0] + equationArray[1] + equationArray[2]);
trace(answer);
```

I'd prefer to use something like this rather than writing a long if statement to pick between different operators if that's possible. *Thanks for the help!*

Comment: This [post](https://forums.adobe.com/message/6040740) should help.

Comment: A [previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002850/inputting-a-equation-in-textfield-and-processing-it-actionscript-3-0/10003467#10003467) might help (though some of the code looks pretty antiquated).

Comment: It's strange but your code works for me I got 6 in answer

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and realized that your code doesn't work only in Chrome.
There is an error

```
SecurityError: Error #2060
   at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
   at FlexTemp/preinitializeHandler()
   at FlexTemp/___FlexTemp_Application1_preinitialize()
   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
   at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
   at mx.core::UIComponent/initialize()
   at spark.components::Application/initialize()
   at FlexTemp/initialize()
   at mx.managers.systemClasses::ChildManager/childAdded()
   at mx.managers.systemClasses::ChildManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
   at mx.managers::SystemManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
   at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::kickOff()
   at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()
   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
   at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()
   at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

but if I switch of PepperFlash\14.0.0.145\pepflashplayer.dll in chrome://plugins/
[image]

all works fine.
I think there are some problems with pepflashplayer.dll

Answer (score 0):

In your flash file:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.text.TextField;
var equationArray:Array = new Array("4","-","8");
var answer:Number = ExternalInterface.call("myJsFunction",equationArray[0] , equationArray[1] , equationArray[2])
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(tf as TextField);
tf.text = answer.toString();
```

In the HTML page (into the  ):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myJsFunction(arg1,arg2,arg3){
            return eval(arg1+arg2+arg3);
        }
    </script>
```

Is this what you try to do?
Using eval like in your code I didn't get the correct answer.
When you run as here above on localhost/server this will give you the answer.

Comment: This is what I want, to a degree. But I forgot to mention, I'm making this as a flash app for an Android device. Is it possible I could just put that JavaScript code into the flash app's directory in a .js file and run it that way? I'm trying it now but I can't get it to work so far. I'm just trying to run it on my computer right now, not sure if Android phones can even run JavaScript files...

Comment: Sorry, I never tried this.
However why don't you want to use switches for the operators???
switch / case / break...

Comment: Sorry, perhaps to avoid to deal with math operator priority!?

Comment: I wanted to try to make my code as compact as possible, I guess that's not necessary. Thanks for your help